# Probability of two of each object

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So if drawing from a pot at random where when an object is drawn there is another one added, so if I draw a red ball a red ball is added so probability remains the same. How can I find the average amount of draws to get 2 or 3 of each object, if all objects have an even chance to be drawn?

Comment: Are you looking for the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called sampling with replacement. For an exact answer, you need to know how many objects you have. For a formula, you need the "Double Dixie Cup Formula". Check out [Numberphile's video](https://youtu.be/aKPkQCys86c) about it.

Let n = the number of objects to be drawn and d = the number of times you want to draw them. Then the expected number of draws is

$$n\cdot\int_0^\infty\bigg[1-\bigg(1-\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\frac{x^i}{i!}}{e^x}\bigg)^n\bigg]dx$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I do know how many objects I am doing this on but I am doing this a couple of times, but the formula was what I was looking for.